# Do I need to define session in every page. I do n't want to be redirected for each page to login

Tags: php, session

I have defined my session in my login page. Once user and password is  entered it lands to predefine  url page. Problem that I can access my other pages with url I want to protect pages with login session.

```
  <?php
       session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $user=$_POST['user'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            $query="SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='$user' && password='$password'";
            $data=mysqli_query($db_conn,$query);
            $total=mysqli_num_rows($data);  

            if($total==1)   {
                echo("Login Sucessfull");
                $_SESSION['log']=1;
                header("refresh:2;url=customer_data_ie.php");   
            }
            elseif($total==is_null()){
               echo("Invalid User");
               header("refresh:2;url=login_page_crm.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "Invalid User";
            }
        }
        ?>

    <?php
    session_start();
    session_destroyed();
    ?>
```

Comment: redirection is the least of your issues, you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: You will need `session_start()` on every PHP page you want to access session data.

Comment: you would be best perhaps to have `session_start()` at the top of every page and don't destroy the session until the state really needs to change ( login,logout, timeout etc )

Comment: `session_destroyed()` **ed**? You mean destroy? Why do you destroy your session you just started?

Comment: On top of what @treyBake mentioned, do not store user's password in plain text, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for better security.

Comment: @RamRaiderit worked thanks all for feed back. Have good one guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this You have to follow below steps :

1. Create header file.
2. Include this header file in the page where your css and js exist.

This is reduce `code duplication` and you will easily manage your web apps.

Let me give you an example of dir stucture

```
/inc/header.php, footer.php
/system/config.php
```

include **header.php** inside this **config.php** and include **config.php** in all the pages so this will include your configuration and header / footer as well.